# date time stamps turned from legible to gibberish in log file -batch file

Tags: batch-file, windows-11-v23h2

I have a batch file which is at the end of this post. One second after I launched the batch file, I opened the log file and found that it contained the following two lines:

```
Fri 03/22/2024 
02:19 PM
```

After the batch file finished running, I opened the log file again. Now, those two lines were gone. Instead, the first few lines are these:

```
䙲椠〳⼲㈯㈰㈴‍ਰ㤺㌵⁁䴍਍
Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.

Verification 0% complete.
Verification 1% complete.
......
```

The log file contains no date or time stamps. Instead, there are three lines of gibberish, one before the first sfc command, one between the two sfc commands, and one after the last sfc command. Their positions correspond to the date time commands in the batch file. It seems the date time stamps have become gibberish.

The above result is repeatable as I have done it several times.

I wonder what happened to the date time stamps. Why are they gibberish? Why did the first date time stamp turned from legible to gibberish?

```
date /t >C:\health.txt
time /t >>c:\health.txt
sfc /scannow >>c:\health.txt
time /t >>c:\health.txt
sfc /scannow >>c:\health.txt
time /t >>c:\health.txt
```

The system is Windows 11 Pro 23H2, Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22687.1000.0.

Comment: What language packs do you have installed

Comment: @Ramhound Traditional Chinese.